# VBA Match and Find Error: No matching type & Undefined Error

Tags: vba, error-handling, macros, find, match

Code

```
    n = Worksheets("Datasheet").UsedRange.Rows.count
    For l = 2 To k
        check = Application.Find(Worksheets("AFAS Dump").Cells(l, 1), Worksheets("Datasheet").Range("K4:K10000000"))
        If check = 0 Then
        Cells(n + 1, 1) = Worksheets("AFAS Dump").Cells(l, 13)
        End If
    Next l
```

> AFAS Dump column 1 contains an amount of nr's. Datasheet also contains an amount of nr's. I want to check whether a nr from AFAS dump is also in Datasheet. If not I want to add that nr to datasheet. I want to use Match or Find but they both give me problems.

Another thing is my K10000000, I want the nr to be changed by a parameter but ive noticed that doesn't work. I prefer Ke where e will be assigned to a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to achieve as you've got a reference to `Column 13` in one of the lines which doesn't make sense if you are trying to add to `Column K`. If you want the macro to check if a number from `Column 1` in the 'AFAS Dump' sheet is in `Column K` of the 'Datasheet' and add it to the bottom of 'Datasheet' if it's not already there then try this:

```
n = Worksheets("Datasheet").Cells(Rows.Count,11).End(xlup).Row
e = Worksheets("AFAS Dump").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Row
For l = 2 To e
    If Worksheetfunction.Match(Worksheets("AFAS Dump").Cells(l, 1), _
    Worksheets("Datasheet").Range("K4:K" & n),0) = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Datasheet").Cells(n + 1, 11) = Worksheets("AFAS Dump").Cells(l, 1)
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next l
```

Comment: yes youre right, 13 must be 1. If i find a nr which is not in "datasheet" but is in "AFAS dump" i want to add it to column 1 in "datasheet". Ill try your code tomorrow. Already thanks for you help.